# (Button) Linking to Another Button that is already within the UIWebview (Swift)

Tags: ios, xcode, swift, button, uiwebview

I am working on an app and I want to make the `UIButton` on my tab bar to do an action, the action would be clicking on another `UIButton` inside my `UIWebView`. So Button 1 on the tab bar when pressed, links to the button 2 that is already embedded in my `UIWebView`.

I would also like the code in `Swift`, not `Objective-C`

Need help!

Comment: Too broad a question.  I'm don't think you understand how StackOverflow.com works. This is not the *starting* point for learning how iOS works and how to code it. Start with some tutorials online, train yourself about the basics of Swift coding and iOS app development. You can also search questions here to get ideas for different aspects of it. But your question requires WAY too much effort from people here.  See [How To Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/review) and [On Topic](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: The purpose of StackOverflow is to help each other out. I already have the knowledge for developing iOS apps. This was an advance feature I thought of making, and wanted help from expertise and professionals.

Comment: To help each other out, yes, but *within* the scope of what is On Topic (see link in my previous comment). People will help, but not help you figure out what kind of bike to buy. The question makes it sound like you don't know much about what you're doing at all and need help with every aspect of it, and design help.  It isn't clear what you're really asking exactly.  "links to button2" what does that even mean?  Links to? Like a web link? Like send a touch event to the UIControl subclass listeners?  Calls the same method?  Just not clear what you are even asking for.

Answer (score 0):

You can make a method, then call it any time you want. So in your case, you would call it in the regular `UIButton`, and in the `UIWebView` `UIButton`.

Hope this helps!!